# Can Zebra Designer import files containing ZPL code

Tags: import, designer, zpl

I'm using Zebra Designer 2.2.2 (Build 2728)

Question

How can i import ZPL Code in the Designer?

Comment: Quick answer, you can't.

Answer (score 5):

This is simply not possible. Zebra Designer was not designed to make a ZPL file backwards into a label-design-file. This is like trying to make a word-document out of a pdf. Sorry, but you have to redesign your label.

Answer (score 4):

Look at http://labelary.com/viewer.html   - An Online ZPL Viewer

This is a site I use to get a good feel for what the label will look like.  It's not always pixel perfect, but is a great reference.